# can't add UIBarButtonItem to navigationController inside of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

```
ViewController *VC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *NavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC];
NavCon.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showall)];
[self.myTabBarController setViewControllers:@[NavCon]];
```

Why it's not adding `UIBarButtonItem` to my navigation controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First remove/comment following line of code

```
NavCon.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showall)];
```

Then put this code in `viewDidLoad` method of viewController of your navContrller.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showall)];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
UITabBarController *my = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    UIViewController *new =  [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:new];
    new.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"+" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:new action:@selector(addButtonClicked:)];
    [my setViewControllers:@[nav]];
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try below code

```
VC.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showall)];
[self.myTabBarController setViewControllers:@[NavCon]];
```

Comment: no it didn't work, but if i do this it worked `VC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"+" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showall)];`